# SQLite FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE CASCADE not working

Tags: sqlite, cascade

I'm running the following script, `wtf.sql`, on SQLite Version 3.16.0:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE 'ZIP'(
  'Zip' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  'City' TEXT NOT NULL,
  'State' TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE 'ADDRESS'(
  'Address_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  'Line_1' TEXT NOT NULL,
  'Line_2' TEXT,
  'Zip' INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY('Zip') REFERENCES ZIP('Zip') ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ZIP('Zip','City','State')
  VALUES ('90210','Beverly Hills','CA')
;
INSERT INTO ADDRESS('Line_1','Line_2','Zip')
  VALUES ('1234 Overpriced House Street','c/o Bob','90210')
;
DELETE FROM ADDRESS
  WHERE Zip = '90210'
;
SELECT *
  FROM ZIP
;
```

Typing the following into bash:

```
$ sqlite3 bits-n-books.db < wtf.sql
```

Returns the following tuple:

```
90210|Beverly Hills|CA
```

What do I need to do to have deletes cascade properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO ADDRESS(Line_1,Line_2,Zip)
  VALUES ('1234 Overpriced House Street','c/o Bob','90210'),
         ('667 Another Street','2nd row','90210');

DELETE FROM ADDRESS WHERE Line_2 = '2nd row';
```

What should happen now? Should all other addresses referring to `90210` also be deleted?

An [ON DELETE CASCADE action](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) deletes any child rows when a parent row is deleted. In this case, this means that deleting a row from `ZIP` will delete all corresponding `ADDRESS` rows. There is no similar mechanism in the other direction.