# Delete cascade doesn't work for sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, cascade

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id         INTEGER      PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                            NOT NULL,
    emp_id     TEXT         REFERENCES title_emp (emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                                          ON UPDATE CASCADE
                                                          MATCH [FULL],
    birth_date DATE,
    first_name VARCHAR (14),
    last_name  VARCHAR (16),
    gender     VARCHAR (6),
    hire_date  DATE,
    mobile     TEXT,
    telephone  TEXT,
    address    TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE title_emp (
    emp_id    TEXT         PRIMARY KEY,
    title     VARCHAR (50),
    from_date DATE,
    to_date   DATE
);
```

I want it so that if a specific employee is deleted, all that follows on title_emp with regard to that employee will be deleted. The DELETE CASCADE doesn't seem to work. As I delete an employee, the title of the employee remains in the title_emp table. What am I doing wrong? Would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be setting up the FK the wrong way around. As it currently stands, if you delete a row from `title_emp`, any `employees` row that references that row will be deleted. From your description, I don't think you want that (and probably just want `emp_id` in `title_emp` to be a FK to `id` in `employees`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE CASCADE not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821480/sqlite-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rows holding foreign keys with delete cascading enabled will delete themselves when the row holding the primary key is deleted. If you delete the row holding the foreign key, the row holding the primary key will not be deleted. This is intentional.

As I understand it, you've a one-to-one or one-to-many relationship where a certain title can can have one or more employees working under it and each employee only has one title.

If it's a one-to-one relationship, you can simply delete the row with the primary key in title_emp. Any employees with foreign keys pointing to that primary key will also be deleted (if you have foreign keys enabled.)

You can enable foreign keys with

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

The same process will work with a one-to-many relationship, if you want to delete a title and all employees working under that title.

If it's a one-to-many relationship and you want the title to be deleted when there are no employees working under that title, cascading delete will be inadequate. you will need to use a trigger instead.

The following trigger will delete the title if the last employee working under that title is deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_unused_title
  AFTER
  DELETE ON
  employees
  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM title_emp WHERE emp_id = OLD.emp_id
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employees WHERE emp_id = OLD.emp_id) = 0;
  END;
```